# Restrict an element's height but show the bottom part instead of the top

Tags: html, css

Using [this sample markup](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/6uXDr/), rather than show the "**1**" in the black box in the top right corner, I want the "**↓**" to show instead, and then it should all appear on hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
#bar ul { margin:0; font-weight:700; position:absolute; bottom:8px; }
```

Comment: Thanks man, I realised at the last minute I had changed to an absolute height instead of `height:auto` which is why when I tried this solution earlier it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the arrow at the top. Then, adjust the `:hover` height down by 2em and add a -2em top margin on the `<ul>` for the hover; this will effectively hide the arrow on hover.

The list would look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>&darr;</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

And the updated CSS would be:

```
#bar:hover { height: 8em; }
#bar:hover ul { margin-top: -2em; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6srun/